# Show white space at the beginning of a text in HTML

Tags: html, whitespace

How do I display white space at the beginning of text in HTML?

For example, I want to use

```
<p>             This is a paragraph.</p> //             This is a paragraph.
```

But it behaves exactly like

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `white-space: pre;` property in CSS which doesn't collapse spaces:

```css
    p {
     white-space: pre;
     color: black;
     background: pink;
    }
```

```html
    <p>             This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 12):

If you have to have spaces you can use `&nbsp;`, so code would look like:

```
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This is a paragraph.</p>
```

For 5 spaces. Though I think you may be best using css to add padding / margin styling to achieve what you are after.

*EDIT*

Snippet added using padding method:

```css
p.padded {
  padding:.3em .5em .1em 2em;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptas, culpa, quam, totam ex illum earum cupiditate, odit delectus cum atque dignissimos. Culpa praesentium perspiciatis incidunt pariatur. Doloremque, illum, sequi.</p>

<p class="padded">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptas, culpa, quam, totam ex illum earum cupiditate, odit delectus cum atque dignissimos. Culpa praesentium perspiciatis incidunt pariatur. Doloremque, illum, sequi.</p>
```

Comment: Actually, yes I add left margin. And this paragraph is just an example, what I exactly want to do is, dipslay a piece of well indented.

Comment: `padding:.3em .5em .1em 2em;` doesnot make any difference. What can be the reason?

Comment: That should be fine. So this in your CSS: p { padding:.3em .5em .1em 2em; }.

Comment: But still, it doesn't intent. Now I'm thinking about replacing spaces with html code.(&nbsp;) I don't know why em doesn't work:/

Comment: Just updated my post with a snippet using your method, it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use this for normal space:

```css
p {
      white-space: pre-line;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To indent a paragraph, use `:before` in CSS

```
p:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To indent a paragraph, use `text-indent:1em;`

You can't create whitespace in HTML as you show because [whitespace is always collapsed](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1) to one space in a text area.