# Formatting system() Output

Tags: php

I want to create a tool to ping a domain and output the time, but when I execute it, it isn't formatted in a way that I want it it's just one huge string.[image]

Here's the code:

```
$result = system("ping -c 1 $q" );
echo "Der Ping zu dieser Domain beträgt: $result ms";
```

I want it somewhat like this:[image]
Thanks for any help

Comment: I believe you are looking for `passthru()` instead of `system()` as explained [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)

Comment: `system` will output whatever the command outputs in the standard output and return the last line. [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) only returns the last line and can (optionally) capture all output which you can then format as you please

Comment: @LelioFaieta but I don't want the raw output, I want formatted output

Comment: @Benni once you have the raw output you can do whatever you want to format it

Comment: @LelioFaieta but how do I format it? it needs to be automated

Comment: But, what format do you want and what have you tried? Do you want an HTML table? A PDF file? Do you want the final stats in green?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not inspect the markup of the given website to see how they formatted the data?

Comment: The screenshot you've added shows literally the raw output of the command which you already have. You're actually asking [how to display carriage returns and white space in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051561/show-white-space-at-the-beginning-of-a-text-in-html/38052592).

Answer (score 1):

try it,that status changing  according  to  os

```
exec("ping -c 1 $q",$output);

print_r($output);
```

other  way

```php
$file=rand(1,1522).'.txt';

exec("ping -c 1 $q >> $file",$output);  //output redirect to file 

sleep(5);
echo file_get_contents($file);
```

Comment: Did not work output is now Array()

Comment: because PHP return array before creating ping response ,you can test 
as such ```ls ,df``` command

Comment: but I need a proper output and it should be formatted

Comment: i am going the added extra  sometings

Comment: Same output, just with a delay

Comment: again try it ..look at txt file